# What is the use of email relay in salesforce?

Tags: email

What is the use of email relay in salesforce. Once we will configure email relay does that mean that every email from saleforce UI will be sent via Configured email relay service and will not consume any email limits.

What are the other use cases in which email relay could be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least a couple of features of email relay which are why organizations choose to use it.

First, there's logging compliance. You can automatically log/record every email sent, including its contents, when you set up a relay. This is useful for organizations that have this requirement, or for organizations that want to have a digital copy of the emails sent that cannot be tampered with.

Second, there's the ability to mitigate filtering by spam filters. Since the emails will come from your own mail servers (after relaying), they are more likely to end up in the Inbox instead of Spam, and won't be affected if Salesforce gets blacklisted (which is rare, and usually quickly rectified, but can be an annoyance).

Note that "bypassing email limits" is not one of the features of using email relay. You still can't send more email than you would normally by using email relay. It is primarily a feature of introducing compliance and increasing email visibility.

Comment: I thought the emails will be sent via outlook email exchange server then we are not utilizing salesforce to send emails. Shouldn't that give unlimited emails. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Salesforce still has to send the emails, they just happen to be going to a different destination. This is explained in other answers and the documentation. The advantages are primarily as outlined above.